# Where could I find Server JRE 8 and is it better than a client-side JRE for a minecraft server (I'm the host)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

everything is in the title, but I'll it in more details here :
I'm actually hosting a minecraft server on one of my pcs, and since the server consists of a bundle of mods, it takes quite the RAM/CPU usage.
It got me interested in Java Server JRE or SE (Standard Edition), to know which would be the most efficient (despite 30Gb of allocated RAM, the server crashed twice or thrice due to a friend making big stuffs, on Java Runtime Environment 8), therefore, I would love to know what would suit me best, SE or Server JRE, and if the last one, where could I find it (for windows).

Thanks for your attention and answers, be safe and have a nice day :)

Comment: what is your MC server ?

Comment: What do you mean ? the version ? the modpack ?

Comment: the mc version of server, 1.8 ? 1.17 ? 1.18 ?

Comment: The server is in 1.16.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should comes on Oracle website, more precisely [here](https://www.oracle.com/fr/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html).

You have to login/sign in/sign up.

Then you will have to find server's JRE at the end, click on good link on right and accept agreement.

Finally, you will be redirected [here](https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u202-b08/1961070e4c9b4e26a04e7f5a083f551e/server-jre-8u202-windows-x64.tar.gz) (link can expire*)

Comment: Thanks for the page, It helped me find the thing I searched for, now I'll do test and see the results in a few days :)
Thanks again :D

Comment: No problem, with pleasure !